# How to get users details when user accessing an APP

Tags: sapui5

How to get a users name and email id when user open an app using his account. we need to provide details based on the users when they open the App. Is there any method in ui5 to get username and email id of the user..

Please help

Comment: Where is the app running?

Comment: SAP FIORI server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get logged username from UserInfo shell service

```
sap.ushell.Container.getService("UserInfo").getId();
```

https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/#/api/sap.ushell.services.UserInfo

Comment: Can we use below code too?                                         onInit : function (evt) {
        var oUserData;
        var y = "http://<your_gateway_system>:<port>/sap/bc/ui2/start_up";
        var xmlHttp = null;
        xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200) {
                oUserData = JSON.parse(xmlHttp.responseText);
               alert(oUserData["fullName"]);
            }
        };
        xmlHttp.open("GET", y, false);
        xmlHttp.send(null);
            },

Comment: Yes, if your app is not running in the SAP Cloud Platform